# Coloring row when ip match in php output with mysql

Tags: php, sql

I have a form and when a user submits the form his ip is logged. I need a way when 2 or more ips match using tables at output to color only the rows with the same ip

```
<?php 
 // Connects to your Database 
 mysql_connect("localhost", "pp", "mygas13") or die(mysql_error()); 
 mysql_select_db("pp") or die(mysql_error()); 
 $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM userTable") 
 or die(mysql_error()); 
 Print "<table border cellpadding=3>"; 
 while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
 { 
 Print "<tr>"; 
 Print "<th>Name:</th> <td>".$info['nick'] . "</td> "; 
 Print "<th>Ip:</th> <td>".$info['ip'] . " </td></tr>"; 
 } 
 Print "</table>"; 
 ?>
```

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```
if($ip = $sameip) {

echo "<td style='background: #fffff;'>$ip</td>";
} else {

echo "<td>$ip</td>";
}
```

This is a bit of a guess due to no code being shown but I think that's what your after?

Comment: yes thanks very much. i was stuch in if($ip = $sameip) .

Comment: Np, next time please show some code and make it clear what you are asking.

Comment: I have added the code can you tell me how to add it?